# How do you describe something that has "just enough" details?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to describe something that is neither too broad and general, nor too detailed. It may be fit to just describe it as "a detailed analysis of so-and-so..", but I want to emphasize the fact that it is not too detailed because I want to point out that it's an advantage that the level of detail lies around the middle of the spectrum.

Is there such a word or phrase that would accomplish that?

EDIT: 
It may help if I try to express what I want to describe. I have a software model that simulates the behavior of a real-life mechanism. I want to emphasize the fact that it is detailed enough that the simulation is accurate, but it's not so detailed that it freezes your computer (or takes a long time to run)

Comment: Something that's is brief enough to get the message across, without being overly "word-ey" could be described as "succinct". i.e, "Explain as best you can, in a succinct manner".

Comment: @i-CONICA Make this an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that's is brief enough to get the message across, without being overly "word-ey", or verbose, could be described as "succinct", or "concise".

i.e, "Explain as best you can, in a [succinct/concise] manner".

Concise is probably used more in common language, though.

Comment: "succinct" portrays the description I'm looking for, but is it suitable to describe something that's not put in words? "A succinct sculpture", for example.

Comment: Hmm, not really. It's really only to describe communication, written or verbal.

Comment: I've just read your edit, and as a software developer myself, I get what you mean. :) You might want to look at words like "optimal", to mean it's been optimised for a purpose, in that it's as clean and neat as it can be.

Comment: In my case, "optimal" may be relative to the application. I think I'm going to describe it as "suffciently-detailed", but it was worth checking for other possibilities.

Comment: +1 But a cite to a reference and a quoted definition would be better.

Comment: I don't think you can use these words for your example though.

Comment: I agree. I think my answer answers the original question, but when the actual context came into it, it's a bit off... But for future people who find this, I think they're good words.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the term **[elegant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/elegant)**.  According to ODO it can mean

> (Of a scientific theory or solution to a problem) pleasingly ingenious and simple:
>   *the grand unified theory is compact and elegant in mathematical terms*

Answer (score 1):

"[the software model] is sufficiently detailed"

Answer (score 0):

[Condensed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Condensed). may also coney the idea:

> 1. To reduce the volume or compass of.
> 2. To make more concise; abridge or shorten.

A condensed version of a piece of writing/book ect.

Also an [abstract](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Condensed):

> 1. A statement summarizing the important points of a text.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

I would use ***[adequate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adequate)***:

> as much or as good as necessary for some requirement or purpose; fully sufficient, suitable, or fit.
>
> <sub><sup>Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adequate</sup></sub>

For example, there is *software adequacy testing* that defines a through test of an application and is used to reach a confidence level that the software will just function enough to be acceptable by users. It is used in white box testing also.

Comment: Unfortunately, *adequate* tends to convey the connotation of "barely adequate" in colloquial speech.

Comment: @outis nihil: Depends on the context. I gave an example related to softwares also.